# Conditional WTFform fields

Tags: python, flask, wtforms, flask-wtforms

I'm working on a flask app and using flask-wtf to help manage my forms. I have the following simplified form:

```
<form id="registerForm" class="form form-register" method="POST" action="" role="form">
        {{ form.hidden_tag() }}
        <div class="form-group">
            {{form.username.label}}
            {{form.username(placeholder="Username", class_="form-control")}}
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            {{form.email.label}}
            {{form.email(placeholder="Email", class_="form-control")}}
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            {{form.password.label}}
            {{form.password(placeholder="Password", class_="form-control")}}
```

There are 2 ways to register on the site -  Either with or without an email token.

If the email has been confirmed the user gets an email containing:

```
http://127.0.0.1:5000/register/ImNsdWVtYXJpbmUzQG1haWxpbmF0b3IuY29tIg.Ca9oUQ.bRJmGYQ1wNqfcQFx1pYyoCEy2oM
```

Otherwise on the site itself the user could click on:

```
 http://127.0.0.1:5000/register
```

The following code can handle both cases:

```
@blueprint.route("/register/", defaults={'token': ''}, methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@blueprint.route("/register/<token>", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def register(token):
    form = RegisterForm(request.form, csrf_enabled=False)
    email = confirm_token(token)
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        new_user = User.create(username=form.username.data,
                              email=form.email.data,
                               password=form.password.data,
                               active=True)
```

If a token is used, I would like to display and validate only 2 form fields (username, password) . If no token - all 3 . How can this be done?

Answer (score 1):

You can create two forms for this, first `BaseRegistrationForm` with `username, password` and `SomeOtherForm` which will inherit from first and have own `email` field.
For me it seems like better approach because it will be more understandable when a year later someone will have to read your code(even you)